# Go internal and pkg packages sharing same name

Tags: go, package

I'm a go newbie and I've been struggling to understand the best practices when it comes to file structure and packages.

From what I've read, the `internal` folder contains code that can't be consumed by clients  and the `pkg` folder contains code that could be used externally.
Say I have a resource that has some internal implementation and also has some functions that could be used externally. Would I just have packages with the same name under both folders like this?

```
- my-app
  - pkg
   - accounts
     - accounts.go (package accounts)
  - internal
   - accounts
     - accounts.go (package accounts)
```

and then when I import I specify `"app/my-app/internal/accounts"` or `"app/my-app/pkg/accounts"` depending on the module I want to import? How do I handle internal and external packages with the same name?

Comment: There is no conflict. Users of your package cannot import my-app/internal/... (that's the point of making the package internal), and when my-app/pkg/accounts imports it, the package name is only used once. That being said, in my experience it is more common to put the internal package close to where it's used (here,  my-app/pkg/internal/accounts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internal packages are described in [the Go command documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Internal_Directories) and [this design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit).

Externally importable packages can be in any folder except an `internal` folder. There is no requirement nor is there a broadly agreed on convention that these packages should be in a `pkg` folder.

Applications can resolve conflicts between packages with the same name by specifying a package name in the [import specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

```
import (
    iaccounts "my-app/internal/accounts"
    accounts "my-app/accounts"
)
```

Use `iaccounts` to refer to the internal package and `accounts` to refer to the regular package.